# Strange effects (inadvertently dividing edges) when doing Maya's extrusion

Tags: maya, 3d-modeling

Firstly, I thought this was the best place to post my question, since there isn't a Maya section or a generic 3-D modeling section, as far as I saw.

I am following a tutorial which can be found here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhPWIDX5iQ0

Currently, I am struggling to figure out what setting I messed with to create such weird effects when I am trying to extrude. Apparently it is dividing every edge connected to the four vertices I am trying to extrude in half, then connecting the new vertices together. You can see the vertices I am extruding in yellow.
[image: Strange extrusion]

Any suggestions on what I may have messed up? I am clueless, and probably don't even know what to search for other than "Strange Maya Extrusion" and "Maya Extrusion Dividing Edges", without any luck. So, anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I am not totally sure your question is on-topic for this site, so I will leave that to experienced reviewers. But for now I edited the title of the question to help detail in it the core of your question. Take a look at it.

Comment: please list all the steps you took to get to this result. it would be good to provide a screenshot before the extrusion too to give us a better idea. I'm pretty sure you are using a wrong tool though. Or maybe you are selecting wrong stuff before extrusion. But I can not say anything else as I don't know what you did exactly.

Comment: OK, my steps are 1) Select the four verts (no others) that I am trying to extrude (this is all one connected 2d face, atm), then press Ctrl+E, which gives me those weird results. I have also tried tinkering with the settings for extrude in the menu but nothing worked.

Comment: @MAnd I am working on this because I am trying to learn modeling so I can begin more 3-D game development, which is why I thought this was the best place. I would have happily put it somewhere else, but I didn't see any other sections for animation, 3d-modeling, or maya (Used my browsers Ctrl+F to look) Thanks for changing the title, though! :)